# Convert mysql query to hibernate criteria

Tags: java

How to convert the following mysql query to hibernate criteria?

```
(sum(case when a.ME_SHAFT_REV=b._40281 and a.ME_Load=b._00026 and a.ME_NO1=b._40195 and a.ME_SCAV_=b._40271 and a.ECA=b._00526 then 1 else 0 end))
```

I have tried the below but it is not working

```
Expression<Integer> sumExp = cb
                .sum((cb.<Integer>selectCase().when(cb.iequal(root.get("me_shaft"), root.get("import2").get("_40281"))
                        ,cb.equal(root.get("me_load"), root.get("import2").get("_00026"))                           
                        , 1).otherwise(0));
```

Comment: Honestly, sometimes it's better to just do a native query

Comment: Preferably formatted and not on a single line